# Logstash influxdb output with geoip filter

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, influxdb, geoip

I’m trying to use logstash geoip filter to send data about location of IP address to InfluxDB via InfluxDB output plugin.

My logstash conf file is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/root/geoip_test.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  geoip {
    source => "message"
    fields => ["latitude", "longitude"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug}
  influxdb {
    host => "localhost"
    port => 8086
    db => "metrics"
    measurement => "geoip_test"
    codec => "json"
    use_event_fields_for_data_points => true
  }
}
```

geoip_test.txt file contains only one IP address:

14.143.35.10

Output with error I receive is:

```
[2020-09-07T12:26:26,696][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
         "geoip" => {
         "latitude" => 12.9771,
        "longitude" => 77.5871
    },
       "message" => "14.143.35.10",
          "path" => "/root/geoip_test.txt",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-09-07T10:26:33.963Z,
          "host" => "test",
      "@version" => "1"
}
[2020-09-07T12:26:34,942][WARN ][logstash.outputs.influxdb][main][941178b6897abb80f9a5f7654e5e62ba752d5e20b68781bc62b466e489c2ce56] Non recoverable exception while writing to InfluxDB {:exception=>#<InfluxDB::Error: {"error":"unable to parse 'geoip_test,host=test geoip={\"latitude\"=\u003e12.9771, \"longitude\"=\u003e77.5871},path=\"/root/geoip_test.txt\" 1599474393963': invalid boolean"}
>}
```

I think geoip filter generates some boolean field which InfluxDB is not able to work with.

Does anyone have any idea what to do with that? Is it possible to set up geoip filter in some way so it wouldn’t generate anything but lon and lat fields?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You are already keeping only the `latitude` and `longitude` fields generated by the `geoip` filter, this is what the `fields` array do. All the fields generated are in the `stdout` output, maybe it could be the `@version` field that is being seen as a boolean? Try to remove it with a `mutate` filter.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've removed the @version field but it didn't help (( When I ingest some logs from file and parse them with logstash there is no problem until I add the geoip filter so I think problem is somewhere there. I've tried a lot of options of configurations with removing and adding some fields or changing data types but nothing helped.